# add_field to elasticsearch document that already exists matching a field from CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, elasticsearch, logstash

I am looking to add a field to an existing document in elasticsearch.  The challenge is the document_id.  I looked up how to update an index and found that it relies on a document ID for matching.  However in my case the document ID I can't match because it's irrelevant to the data I need to match.

To build the initial index I utilize a postgres connection through logstash.  Logstash then mutates the data that I need and puts it into a logstash.  Below is phase 1 which is inputing the data to build the index.

**PHASE 1**

```
input {
jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1"
        jdbc_user => "dbuser"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true        
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/logstash/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement_filepath => "/home/logstash/queries/combinedstats.sql"
}
}
filter {
mutate {
rename => { "stats_time" => "date" }
rename => { "encode" => "uuid" }

add_field => {

    "field_1" => "Testing"
}
    ########################################################################
    # Do not modify this tag # 
    add_tag => ["Combined_Stats"]
########################################################################
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
    action => "index"
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]  
    index => ["assessments5"]   
}
}
```

**PHASE 2**
I would like to add the VM name to the UUID.  I have a CSV file that is built like the following:

```
"Name","Uuid","DataStore"
"WinDesk_7","50303a09-4f40-a440-530c-62253302b5ed"
"vpool03","50337efc-58f1-9945-205d-89e9e5a8a3c1"
```

I want to take the Name of the VM and add it to a field to the UUID.

Tis is a record from the elastic search cluster.

```
@version:1 @timestamp:May 23rd 2016, 10:30:07.229 date:May 23rd 2016, 10:19:00.000 uuid:50337efc58f19945205d89e9e5a8a3c1 tags:Combined_Stats _id:AVTec7vx2x7Yt90z2uBS _type:logs _index:assessments5 _score:
```

First thing i need to do is get rid of the dashes within logstash.  Here is my import of the CSV file so far using logstash.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/logstash/healthCheck/originalVMinfo.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
     }
}
filter {
  csv {
        columns => ["Name", "Uuid","DataStore","host","CurrentPolicy"]
        separator => ","
  }
  mutate{
        gsub => ["Uuid", "-", " "]
  }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
#   elasticsearch {
#   action => "index"
#   index => "assessments5"
#   #document_type => san_stats
#   #document_id => "%{uuid}"
#   hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
#   #workers => 1
#   }
#}
```

**End Result**
I need to add a tag the UUIDS with a VM name.

```
@version:1 @timestamp:May 23rd 2016, 10:30:07.229 date:May 23rd 2016, 10:19:00.000 uuid:50337efc58f19945205d89e9e5a8a3c1 tags:Combined_Stats, **vpool03** _id:AVTec7vx2x7Yt90z2uBS _type:logs _index:assessments5 _score:
```

**Edit**

Combined the two instead of having multiple input configs.

```
input {
    jdbc {
        type => "stats"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"
        jdbc_user => "dbuser"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true        
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/logstash/postgresql-9.4.1208.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement_filepath => "/home/logstash/queries/combinedstats.sql"
}
file {
    type => "vmName"
    path => ["/home/logstash/healthCheck/originalVMinfo.csv"]
    start_position => "beginning"
}
}
filter {
if [type] == "stats"{
mutate {
rename => { "stats_time" => "date" }
rename => { "encode" => "uuid" }

    # Do not modify this tag # 
    add_tag => ["Combined_Stats"]

 }

 ruby {
  code => "  take input from jdbc and utilize the uuid as the primary key.
  search csv file for matching UUID and take the corresponding Name field and add as tag " 
 }  

}
if [type] == "vmName"{
    csv {
        columns => ["Name", "Uuid","DataStore","host","CurrentPolicy"]
        separator => ","
    }
    mutate{
        gsub => ["Uuid", "-", ""]
    }
}
}
output {
if [type] == "stats" {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]  
        index => ["assessments7"] # MUST BE LOWER CASE      
    }       
}
if [type] == "vmName" {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
        index => "csv4"
    }
}
}
```

Logstash has the ability to do ruby code which could be what i am missing.

Comment: Side note the `"` In the CSV are causing issues with the CSV parsing.

Comment: I don't have time to fully look into your situation but you can use the Elasticsearch filter to query ES and then use the results on the current log you're processing. You might be able to use it to do what you want to do. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html